# When installing Ubuntu onto USB drive, mount point differs from when launching with it

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, usb, live-usb

So I installed Ubuntu onto a USB flash drive (like actually installed it, not made a LiveUSB. I used an existing liveUSB to press install and put it on the other USB drive instead of that one). Now when I installed it, the USB drive was located in /dev/sdc, but when I try to boot from it, it is located at /dev/sdb, and I get the error `/dev/sdc1 does not exist`. How can that be fixed?

Is there a way to make this work on any position (e.g. sda / adb / adc etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with UUID's. Some time ago Ubuntu started using UUID's because it is not known in what order USB devices are mounted (1 might be mounting quicker at a given time than at another given time).

All you need to know can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

To get a list of all the UUIDs, use one of the following two commands:

```
sudo blkid
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Example mounting with UUID:

```
UUID=3f8c5321-7181-40b3-a867-9c04a6cd5f2f  /media/data  ext3  relatime,noexec  0  2
```

So in short ...

- get the UUID
- edit `/etc/fstab` on the USB stick
- replace /dev/sdb1 with the UUID

Comment: where is /etc/fstab found? liveUSB on whicj I install linux from or USB where it is installed?

Comment: I just checked and the file (on the USB with installed ubuntu on it) already has the UUID. it says on the last line UUID = .....[uuid - checked and it is correct] / ext2 errors=remount-ro 0    1

Comment: #1 fstab on the usb #2 that is weird... It is the one thing I know that could cause this. UUID should always be the same (unless you re-calculate it yourself).

Comment: no the UUID of the Ubuntu USB is already found in the fstab file. it isthe correct UUID bu the problem still accurs

Comment: well turns out changing the file doesnt help at all and the same problem keeps on happening